# Ember 3.19 Proper way of updating a record and saving it in an API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I have a small Tic Tac Toe game, and I have a scoreboard functionality. I made a Rails API that will hold a global list of these scores.

What is the proper way for me to update the records on my Rails backend from Ember?

Currently what I'm trying to get to work is:

In my `application.js` route I have

```js
async model() {
    return {
        score: this.store.findAll('score')
    }
}
```

My `game` router has

```js
model() {
    return {
      score: this.store.peekAll("score")
    }
  }
```

In my `game.hbs` template, I have a button with an onClick `sendScore()` method in the `game.js` controller. This method will look at the store for a specific username (users can enter a username under which their scores will be kept in the rails DB), and upon finding the user what it should be doing is setting the scores for this user to be equal to a localStorage item.

```js
sendScore() {
    const entry = this.store.peekAll('score').filterBy("username", localStorage.getItem("username"))[0]
    entry.wins = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("wins"));
    entry.losses = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("losses"));
    entry.draws = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("draws"));
    entry.save();
}
```

But this doesn't work.

As an example of what currently happens

I start off with a username "damion" that has 150 wins, 146 draws and 318 losses.

If I console.log `entry.wins` after the `entry.wins = parseInt...`, the record has clearly updated with whatever is in localStorage. However, upon calling `entry.save()`, the PATCH request that gets sent out by Ember has values that are unchanged from what it originally was.

What is the proper way of doing this?

EDIT: My Ember Data `score` model looks like this

```js
import Model, { attr } from '@ember-data/model';

export default class ScoreModel extends Model {
  @attr username;
  @attr wins;
  @attr draws;
  @attr losses;
}
```

Very simple model. My adapter just has `host = localhost:3000` and nothing else in it.

`ember-source` and `ember-data` are both version `~3.19.0`

I also checked using `entry.changedAttributes()` in the line before I call my `save()`, and sure enough Ember can see that I changed my values.

```js
draws: (2) [146, 0]
losses: (2) [318, 5]
wins: (2) [150, 56]
```

Comment: Can you please include the Ember Data model as well? That would be helpful. What versions of `ember-source` and `ember-data` are you using?

Comment: @jelhan I've updated the post with the model and version info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've identified the issue.

Ember will POST/PATCH things after it serializes things via the JSON:API spec, and and the problem was that my Rails backend didn't pick up the body of the request, as it was only looking for URL Params.

At this point there's a few options, and I just went with the simpler solution of sending manual POST/PATCH requests to the appropriate endpoints.